# Scala Remote Actors stop client from terminating

Tags: scala, actor

I am writing a simple chat server, and I want to keep it as simple as possible. My server listed below only receives connections and stores them in the clients set. Incoming messages are then broadcasted to all clients on that Server. The server works with no problem, but on the client side, the RemoteActor stops my program from termination. Is there a way to remove the Actor on my client without terminating the Actor on the Server?

I don't want to use a "one actor per client" model yet.

```
 import actors.{Actor,OutputChannel}
 import actors.remote.RemoteActor

 object Server extends Actor{
  val clients = new collection.mutable.HashSet[OutputChannel[Any]]
  def act{
   loop{
    react{
     case 'Connect =>
      clients += sender
     case 'Disconnect =>
      clients -= sender
     case message:String =>
      for(client <- clients)
      client ! message
    }
   }
  }

  def main(args:Array[String]){
   start
   RemoteActor.alive(9999)
   RemoteActor.register('server,this)
  }
 }
```

my client would then look like this

```
val server = RemoteActor.select(Node("localhost",9999),'server)
server.send('Connect,messageHandler) //answers will be redirected to the messageHandler
/*do something until quit*/
server ! 'Disconnect
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795863/how-to-terminate-scala-remote-actor-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest placing the client side code into an actor itself - ie not calling alive/register in the main thread

(implied by [http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/actors/remote/RemoteActor$.html](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/actors/remote/RemoteActor%24.html))

something like

```
//body of your main: 
val client = actor { 
   alive(..)
   register(...)
   loop { 
       receive {
           case 'QUIT => exit()
       }
    } 
}
client.start
//then to quit:
client ! 'QUIT
```

Or similar (sorry I am not using 2.8 so might have messed something up - feel free to edit if you make it actually work for you !).

Comment: hmm.. markdown really doesn't like the single quote as symbol thing... should I change it to use something else ?

Comment: that won't work, because register is ServerOnly, and I don't want that the server has to connect to the clients