# Should I only send actor messages from inside an actor using modern Akka?

Tags: scala, actor

On the question about [Actor Worst Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549251/scala-actors-worst-practices), one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1553242/350351) says:

> Always send a message from an Actor-subsystem thread. If this means
>   creating a transient Actor via the Actor.actor method then so be it:
>
> ```
> case ButtonClicked(src) => Actor.actor { controller ! SaveTrade(trdFld.text) }
> ```

The answer was written in 2009. Is this currently a good practice? Does it apply to Akka actors?

I don't think my question is a duplicate of [Is it bad practice to send an actor a message from something which is not an actor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058408/is-it-bad-practice-to-send-an-actor-a-message-from-something-which-is-not-an-act?rq=1) because that is referring to an older implementation of the actor system. It does explain the rationale behind the "Worst Practices" post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Akka does not have the issue that the old Scala actors had, where an `ActorProxy` could potentially be created for each thread, that would then leak memory in its ever-growing mailbox.

Let's look at `!`:

```
def !(message: Any)(implicit sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Unit
```

If you are sending a message, and you aren't inside another `Actor`, the the sender defaults to `Actor.noSender`. To quote the docs:

> Default placeholder (null) used for "!" to indicate that there is no
>   sender of the message, that will be translated to the receiving
>   system's deadLetters.

If the Actor you are sending to tries to reply, you will get dead letters. These can be logged if desired, but they won't result in a memory leak.